# PayPal IPN Bad Request 400 Error

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

Using the PayPal IPN, I keep getting an error 400.

I have been making the script send me emails of `$res` to see what the response is, inside of the `while (!feof($fp)) {}` loop. I always end up getting the error: `HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request`

In total I get back:

```
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
​Connection: close
Server: BigIP
Content-Length: 19
​Invalid Host Header
```

​The last line after this is just blank. Here is my code, I have tried changing loads of things but nothing works.

```
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
$value = preg_replace('/(.*[^%^0^D])(%0A)(.*)/i','${1}%0D%0A${3}', $value);// IPN fix
$req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

$fp = fsockopen('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

if (!$fp) {
// HTTP ERROR
} else {
   fputs($fp, $header . $req);
   while (!feof($fp)) {
       $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
       if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
           //ADD TO DB
       } else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
           // PAYMENT INVALID & INVESTIGATE MANUALY!
           // E-mail admin or alert user
       }
   }
   fclose ($fp);
}
```

I have added a line, this is the header before it is sent:

```
 Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com
 POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
 Content-Length: 1096
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Since you're opening the socket yourself, rather than using an HTTP library such as curl, you need to set the proper HTTP Protocol version and add the [HTTP Host header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.23) yourself just below the POST line.

```
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header .= "Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com\r\n";
```

Comment: You should also change 'HTTP/1.0' to 'HTTP/1.1'.

Comment: Actually, it is. The 'Host' header is not part of the HTTP/1.0 protocol, so the correct answer is; you'll need to add the 'Host' header *and* move to HTTP/1.1.

Comment: I don't understand why this Host header is needed. Two years ago I set up an IPN listner - today when I needed to update it and test it on localhost I found that I was getting errors when POSTing back to HTTP (it now gave 302). After switching to SSL, like in this example I also got 400. And adding Host header worked - but my live IPN already used SSL without the Host header. :s So why does localhost IPS require it?

Comment: Also, when I tried HTTP/1.1 the PayPal IPN Tester tool would return an error - it didn't seem to like it. Switching back to 1.0 and everything worked again.

Comment: Reading this post at PayPal's forum: https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Selling-on-your-website/IPN-response-problem/td-p/519862?profile.language=en-gb It's not just me seeing this. Live code works without Host header, but Sandbox bombs with 400. I noticed the PayPal example has been updated from the PHP4 version I used to PHP5.2 with cURL. I guess I'll try and migrate to avoid any potential future problems.

Comment: My best guess would be that the sandbox is on a machine serving multiple virtual hosts, while live is only serving www.paypal.com.

Comment: My fix: change from HTTP/1.0 to HTTP/1.1

Comment: @NeedleNoseNeddy The question is outdated, too. I don't understand what you intend by your comment.

Answer (score 29):

I was having the same issues and these are the required changes.  Some of the answers above dont fix all the problems.

New format for header:

```
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com\r\n";  // www.paypal.com for a live site
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n";
$header .= "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
```

Note the extra set of \r\n on the last line only.
Also, the string compare no longer works because a newline is being inserted in the response from the server so change this:

```
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0)
```

to this:

```
if (stripos($res, "VERIFIED") !== false)  // do the same for the check for INVALID
```

Comment: This is the correct answer as of Oct-2013, as I tried the other answers and did not work. My PayPal-IPN code is based on this site -> https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/gs_IPN/ and adding this code above make it works in sandbox !

Comment: U just saved me!

Answer (score 2):

https://www.x.com/content/bulletin-ipn-and-pdt-scripts-and-http-1-1

```
// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header .="POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header .="Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .="Host: www.paypal.com\r\n";
$header .="Connection: close\r\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found PayPals example code using fsockopen not to work properly.

To make IPN work with PHP I used Aireff's suggestion from Aug 5 and looked at the code using curl technique on x.com site.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the best thing is to use the paypal sample code... It works perfectly then : https://www.x.com/developers/PayPal/documentation-tools/code-sample/216623

Comment: That sample code has change since two years ago when I first set up my IPN. The old one was made for PHP4 I think - it now fails in sandbox mode by still works live. Though that makes me nervous and I'll be migrating the code to the newer example.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to trim the $res before comparison..

```
$res = fgets ($fp, 1024);

$res = trim($res); //NEW & IMPORTANT
```