# paypal ipn - no reply from paypal after postback

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I am working on Paypal IPN. My application managed to receive the first notification from Paypal, however, after sending the postback, there seem to be no reply from paypal whether the postback is valid or invalid.

Majority of the code i got it from the sample code from paypal developer website:

```
public function process(){

// Read the notification from PayPal and create the acknowledgement response
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';               // add 'cmd' to beginning of the acknowledgement you send back to PayPal

//$raw = file_get_contents("php://input");
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {         // Loop through the notification NV pairs
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));  // Encode the values
    $req .= "&$key=$value";                    // Add the NV pairs to the acknowledgement
}

//Set up the acknowledgement request headers
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n";
$header .= "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";

//Open a socket for the acknowledgement request
//$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

// Post request back to PayPal for validation
fputs ($fp, $header . $req);


while (!feof($fp)) {                     // While not EOF
    $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);              // Get the acknowledgement response
    //$res=stream_get_contents($fp, 1024);

    $this->emailtest(print_r($_POST,true) .'<br /><br />' . $header.$req);
    if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {  // Response is VERIFIED

        $this->emailtest('VERIFIED');
        // Send an email announcing the IPN message is VERIFIED
        //$mail_From = "IPN@example.com";
        //$mail_To = "Your-eMail-Address";
        //$mail_Subject = "VERIFIED IPN";
        //$mail_Body = $req;
        //mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, $mail_Body, $mail_From);

        // Notification protocol is complete, OK to process notification contents

        // Possible processing steps for a payment might include the following:

        // Check that the payment_status is Completed
        // Check that txn_id has not been previously processed
        // Check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
        // Check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
        // Process payment

    }

    else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) { // Response is INVALID

        $this->emailtest('INVALID');
        // Notification protocol is NOT complete, begin error handling

        // Send an email announcing the IPN message is INVALID
        $mail_From = "IPN@example.com";
        $mail_To = "Your-eMail-Address";
        $mail_Subject = "INVALID IPN";
        $mail_Body = $req;
        mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, $mail_Body, $mail_From);
    }
}
fclose ($fp);
```

}

My header looks something like this: [from concatenating $header.$req]:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
Content-Length: 960 
Connection: close

cmd=_notify-validate&mc_gross=30.00&protection_eligibility=Eligible&address_status=confirmed&payer_id=V6AHFXYY8YVFU&tax=0.00&address_street=1+Main+St&payment_date=09%3A20%3A02+Jul+06%2C+2013+PDT&payment_status=Completed&charset=windows-1252&address_zip=95131&first_name=LY&mc_fee=1.37&address_country_code=US&address_name=LY+Y&notify_version=3.7&custom=&payer_status=verified&business=test-facilitator%40hotmail.com&address_country=United+States&address_city=San+Jose&quantity=1&verify_sign=ALty0ZLnfvwh23G8AkAyx34uB78KAtFMUzdUnz11sJNJNFF4NI8JnFNu&payer_email=test%40hotmail.com&txn_id=2VB92036BK537324F&payment_type=instant&last_name=Y&address_state=CA&receiver_email=test-facilitator%40hotmail.com&payment_fee=&receiver_id=82EXQSKTSV6ZN&txn_type=web_accept&item_name=Chef&mc_currency=SGD&item_number=1&residence_country=US&test_ipn=1&handling_amount=0.00&transaction_subject=Chef&payment_gross=&shipping=0.00&ipn_track_id=1dc5a2e7b3934
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this through another reference, or at least, get a reply from IPN [invalid replies] - its a progress after all:

Referred to: [PayPal IPN Bad Request 400 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810344/paypal-ipn-bad-request-400-error)

Changing header format to:

```
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com\r\n";  // www.paypal.com for a live site 
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n"; 
$header .= "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
```

And changing:

> if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0)

to this:

> if (stripos($res, "VERIFIED") !== false)

Answer (score 0):

thanks! I tried to make the change to HTTP 1.1 this evening, and did not recognise any response returned from PayPal until I changed my check for the 'verified' to match your version

```
    if (stripos($res, "VERIFIED") !== false) :
```

It now works a treat with the live PayPal site

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to remove the connection close header, and add a trim to the response back from PP. Here are the headers:

```
$header  = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Host: www.paypal.com\r\n"; 
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
```

Here is the fsockopen:

```
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

and here is the trim on the response back from PP:

```
if (!$fp) {
// HTTP ERROR
  error_mail("Could not open socket");
//
} else {
  fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
  while (!feof($fp)) {
    $res = trim(fgets ($fp, 1024));
    }
//
// check the payment_status is Completed
// check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
//
  if ((strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) && ($payment_status == "Completed") && ($receiver_email == $valid_receiver_email)) {
```

That worked for me.